# Text Comparison not working properly in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an issue when I try to merge one list into another list. My specific issue at the moment is that it wants to place "Country Way Main" after "CPF Derby West House". I have made sure that both cells are text.

```
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
rowidx_mo = 2
rowidx_ma = 2
For rowidx_mo = 2 To lastRow
Comp_1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(rowidx_mo, 5)
Comp_2 = Wbook(1).Worksheets("TestHistory").Cells(rowidx_ma, 5)
Comp_3 = ActiveSheet.Cells(rowidx_mo, 4)
Comp_4 = Wbook(1).Worksheets("TestHistory").Cells(rowidx_ma, 4)

Do While Comp_1 > Comp_2
    rowidx_ma = rowidx_ma + 1
    Comp_2 = Wbook(1).Worksheets("TestHistory").Cells(rowidx_ma, 5)
    Comp_4 = Wbook(1).Worksheets("TestHistory").Cells(rowidx_ma, 4)
Loop

If (Comp_1 < Comp_2) Then
    'insert test into aggregate
        Range(Cells(rowidx_mo, 1), Cells(rowidx_mo, 9)).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Wbook(1).Activate
        Range(Cells(rowidx_ma, 1), Cells(rowidx_ma, 9)).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
ElseIf (Comp_1 = Comp_2) Then

        Do While Comp_3 > Comp_4
            rowidx_ma = rowidx_ma + 1
            Comp_4 = Wbook(1).Worksheets("TestHistory").Cells(rowidx_ma, 4)
        Loop

        If (Comp_3 < Comp_4) Then
        'test exists in aggregate, but not specific location
            Range(Cells(rowidx_mo, 1), Cells(rowidx_mo, 9)).Select
            Selection.Cut
            Wbook(1).Activate
            Range(Cells(rowidx_ma, 1), Cells(rowidx_ma, 9)).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        ElseIf (Comp_3 = Comp_4) Then
            Cells(rowidx_mo, 9).Select
            Selection.Cut
            Wbook(1).Activate
            Cells(rowidx_ma, 10).Select
            Selection.Insert
        End If
End If

rowidx_ma = rowidx_ma + 1
Wbook(2).Activate

Next
```

The code works properly until rowidx_mo reaches "23" At this point, it should 
enter this loop:

```
Do While Comp_3 > Comp_4
    rowidx_ma = rowidx_ma + 1
    Comp_4 = Wbook(1).Worksheets("TestHistory").Cells(rowidx_ma, 4)
Loop
```

And stop when Comp_3 is "Country Way Main" and Comp_4 is "CPFDerby Main House" Instead, it continues the while loop passing the following strings "CPFFG Bungalow", and "CPHeights Bungalow" before it finally inserts the "Country Way Main" before "Martin Street"

When I sort in excel, it places the names in the order I would expect. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the title is misleading because you aren't using the `StrComp` function - you're using the comparison operator `>`. The long and short of it is that it uses the comparison method that is specified with `Option Compare`.

I'm guessing you don't have `Option Compare` *set*, so it is defaulting to `Option Compare Binary`.  Now, considering the 2 strings that you mention at the start of your question, `CPF Derby West House` will be "less than" `Country Way Main` because the ASCII value of 'P' is 80 and the ASCII value of 'o' is 111.

If you want to use case insensitive string comparison, either specify `Option Compare Text` or actually *use* the [`StrComp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264346.aspx) function and pass it the `compare` argument of `vbTextCompare`:

```
'Returns 1, because with text comparison, the first string is greater than the second.
Debug.Print StrComp("CPF Derby West House", "Country Way Main", vbTextCompare)
```

Comment: I was using StrComp to debug... I have since removed it from the description. Going forward, I'll use the StrComp with vbTextCompare. Thank you!

Comment: @ezcheez - NP - if you do decide to go with `Option Compare Text`, I'd recommend putting that code in it's own module so it doesn't effect other string comparisons in different procedures.